# Finding Third Quartile from Probability Generating Function

Tags: probability

Suppose that a random variable X has a probability generating function:

> hx(t)=.10+.18t+.12t^2+.37t^5+.23t^8

What is the value of the third quartile? I have no idea how to approach this problem. I just know that third quartile is 75th percentile.The question does not state the total number of variables. I know that mean is the first derivative of the probability generating function when t=1.

> h'x(t)=.18+.24t+1.85t^4+1.84t^7.

If I plug in t=1, I would get the mean to be 4.11. Does the mean help to get third quartile? Mean= Ex/n, I have the mean, but is there any way I could get the Ex? Help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

The coefficients of the prob gen function are the probabilities $X$ takes the the various integer values, so $P(X=0) = .10,$ $P(X=1) = .18,$ $P(X=5) = .37,$ and  $P(X=8) = .23$. From these you should be able to find the third quartile using its defintion as the smallest number that $X$ has a $\leq 25\%$ chance of being greater than (precise definitions vary).